# if-else Block Raises a "control reaches end of non-void function" Warning

Tags: c++, if-statement, warnings

I'm creating a collision checking functions based on thee geometric shapes: lines, rectangles and circles. I wrote a Line-Line checking function which looks something like this:

```
bool check_collision(jLine L1, jLine L2, double singular_threshold=1e-6){
    /*Variable definitions omitted for brevity*/

    if (parallel){
        return false;
    }
    else if (infinite){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        jVector t;
        t = M.inverse()*(s2 - s1);
        double t1 = t.get_x(), t2 = t.get_y();

        on1 = (0. <= t1) and (t1 <= 1.);
        on2 = (0. <= t2) and (t2 <= 1.);

        if (seg1){
            if (not on1){
                return false;
            }
            else if (seg2){
                if (not on2){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if (on2){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All variables and types are properly defined and do not cause any problems. However, when I compile this code, and warning is given that "control reaches end of non-void function". This warning seems to indicate that my `if-else` tree contains a branch where there is no `return` statement. However, as far as I can tell, every branch ends in the return of a `bool` type object. Am I missing something?

The warning is removed when I add a `return true;` at the very end of the function, but I feel as though this should not be necessary. I also hypothesized that this warning is raised anytime an if-else chain is used. I refuted this with another function that consisted entirely of an if-elif-else chain:

```
bool check_collision(jRect R1, jRect R2){
    if (R2.left() > R1.right()){
        return false;
    }
    else if (R2.right() < R1.left()){
        return false;
    }
    else if (R2.top() > R1.bottom()){
        return false;
    }
    else if (R2.bottom() < R1.top()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

The warning is not raised when this function is compiled. Can anybody shed some light on what I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "as far as I can tell, every branch ends in the return of a bool" -- Wrong. The following leads to no `return` statement: `if (seg1) { if (not on1) { ... } else if (seg2) { ... } }`, this does not return anything for the `else` case (which is not provided).

Comment: @JamesAdkison: Hi there. This is the comment section, which is for critiquing and requesting clarification. You are welcome to post answers in the answer section, which you may find below this comment. On Stack Exchange we have a Q&A model; questions and answers may be voted-on, reviewed and collaboratively-edited. Comments cannot, and as such they are not appropriate for giving answers. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm aware of the answer section and I upvoted yours. The reason I left a comment versus an answer is that I didn't feel my comment alone was sufficiently complete to make an answer and I didn't feel like elaborating further. However, I still wanted to point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: Comments are not subject to the quality control mechanisms that answers are. Although you were correct in this instance, who's to say that you're pointing the OP in the right direction? When you write an answer in a comment, you take away the community's ability to properly peer review your answer. Please stick to comments only in the comments section. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, every branch ends in the return of a bool type object. Am I missing something?

Well, yes.

```
        if (not on1){
            return false;
        }
        else if (seg2){
            if (not on2){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
```

In this section of the code, your `if` has an `else if` but no `else`. If the `else` is "triggered", the function runs out of code before hitting a `return` statement.

The compiler is warning you that you did not write any code to handle the case when `on1 && !seg2`. If this condition is not possible, we cannot say because we cannot see `seg2`; but, more to the point, the compiler cannot say either.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. You and James Adkinson found the part that I missed.